# How to set rows to be displayed in angular 7 data table without pagination

Tags: datatable, angular-material, angular7

I'm using angular 7 data table .. but instead of displaying complete array of data I  want to display only 10 rows in the table based on my condition.I don't want use pagination also ..

Comment: Please show what you've tried and try to provide a bit of code for us help you more efficiently

Comment: Yes I got the solution .. now i'm looping through the array with count variable and pushing first 10 elements to another array then assigning that array to datasource and displaying.

Thanks for reply :)